# replication operator with 0

Tags: operators, verilog, system-verilog

I have RTL code in which the replication index in the replicator operator is 0.

```
inst (. in ( { {0{1'b0}}, 1'b1 })
```

I am not able to predict the behavior here.
I didn't find anything specified in **`LRM for 0 or negative replication index in replication operator`**.

Answer (score 4):

This often occurs where you have a parametrised bit width and 1 bit wide is an allowed value.

```
parameter WIDTH = 1;
inst ( .in ( { {WIDTH-1{1'b0}}, 1'b1 }) );
```

Which results a warning along the lines of :

> Warning: : Non-positive replication multiplier inside concat. Replication will be ignored.

To avoid the warning you could use generates:

```
parameter WIDTH = 1;
wire [WIDTH-1:0] connection;

generate 
  if (WIDTH > 1) begin
    assign connection = { {WIDTH-1{1'b0}}, 1'b1 };
  end
  else begin
    assign connection = 1'b1 ;
  end
endgenerate 


inst ( .in( connection ) );
```

Or over-sizing, by 1 bit.

```
parameter WIDTH = 1;
wire [WIDTH:0] connection = { {WIDTH{1'b0}}, 1'b1 } ;
inst ( .in ( connection[WIDTH-1:0] ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

The 1800-2012 LRM says

> A replication operation may have a replication constant with a value
>   of zero. This is useful in parameterized code. A replication with a
>   zero replication constant is considered to have a size of zero and is
>   ignored. Such a replication shall appear only within a concatenation
>   in which at least one of the operands of the concatenation has a
>   positive size.

So your expression will be treated as a 1-bit value 1'b1.